# Why do Excel sheets have to be activated before selection?

Tags: vba, excel, datamodel

This code

```
Sheets(1).Activate
Sheets(2).Range("A1").Select
```

will fail in VBA because you can only use `Select` on an object which is `Active`. I understand this is the case.

What element of the Excel datamodel causes this to be the case? I would think there is an implicit intent from a user/coder to `Activate` any object immediately prior to using `Select` - I do not understand why VBA would not make this assumption, and, I am assuming there is a reason this distinction exists.

- What part of Excel's datamodel prevents selection without activation?

Comment: All of it. It's designed to work that way from the bottom up, and it makes perfect sense. Try to select something with your mouse without the area under it being active, or mark text for a selection in a window without the window being active (focused) first, or type keys on your keyboard without touching the keyboard to make it active. Your code can't **assume** anything; you have to be specific.

Comment: @KenWhite that's my point. It seems like there are no circumstances in which you would want to `Select` in which not `Activating` makes sense (all your examples reinforce this point) - so I do not understand why VBA does not automatically do this whenever you call `Select`.

Comment: Because that's not the way it was designed from the beginning, and changing it now would probably break lots of existing code. Maybe Joel Spolsky (one of the original creators of VBA for Excel and a co-creator of this site) will see this and explain why the decision was made in the first place, but anything else would just be speculation.

Comment: I'm missing something - that code will work fine in VBA. A bit of trivia, `Select` has `False` as an optional argument

Comment: @brettdj sorry, I "copied" code from memory from another answer which wasn't enough! I have updated it correctly...

Comment: Thanks for the update. I realise your question is on design intent, but if you ever did need to activate a range then `Application.Goto Sheets(2).Range("A1")` is a much better option to use.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but are you sure you really need to select the cell in the first place? Most likely you just need to reference it in some way. To copy a cell value to another sheet for example you don't need to select one cell and then the other one, just do `sheet1.range("A1") = sheet2.range("A1")`. Activating a sheet and selecting a range is usually inefficient.

Comment: Frustratingly, Excel is able to do this internally with the `.pivotselect` method. There's just no way to get the resulting selection without activating the sheet!

Answer (score 5):

As brettdj pointed out, you do not have to activate the sheet in order to select a range. Here's a reference with a surprisingly large amount of [examples for selecting cells/ranges](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291308).

Now as for the why do I have to active the sheet first? I do not believe it is a fault of the datamodel, but simply a limitation of the select method for Ranges.

From experimentation, it looks like there are two requirements to select a range in Excel.

1. Excel must be able to update the UI to indicate what is selected.
2. The ranges parent (I.E. the sheet) must be active.

To support this claim, you also cannot select a cell from a hidden sheet.

```
Sheets(1).Visible = False
Sheets(1).Activate
'The next line fails because the Range cannot be selected.
Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
```

Simply put, when it comes to Ranges, you cannot select one you cannot see.

I would have claimed this is a limitation of select all together, except that you can actually select an object in a hidden sheet. Silly Excel.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is a bit late to the party, but I discovered a hack to do this...

Try this code:

```
Sheets(1).Activate
Sheets(2).Range("A1").Copy
Sheets(2).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Note that it is a hack, but it does the trick!!

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Cook: thanks for your response, but unfortunately Excel itself doesn't play by the same rules imposed on Excel Macros...

To illustrate, I'll briefly present my current problem...

I'm attempting to re-set a table's contents to a common state. This method will be applied to multiple tables across various sheets:

```
Public Sub restoreTable()
    Dim myTableSheet As Worksheet: Set myTableSheet = Range("Table1").Parent
    Dim myTable As ListObject: Set myTable = myTableSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

    ' --- Clear Table's Filter(s)
    If myTable.ShowAutoFilter Then ' table has auto-filters enabled
        Call myTable.Range.AutoFilter ' disables autofilter
    End If
    myTable.Range.AutoFilter ' re-apply autofilter

    ' --- Sort by Sequence number
    Call myTable.Sort.SortFields.Clear ' if not cleared, sorting will not take effect

    myTable.Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[#Data],[Column1]]"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    myTable.Sort.Header = xlYes
    myTable.Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    myTable.Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
    Call myTable.Sort.Apply

    myTable.Sort.SortFields.Clear
End Sub
```

For each use-case below, `Table1` is found in `Sheet1`

**Use-Case 1:**

- Activate `Sheet1`, select range `A1`
- Run `restoreTable`
- observe: range `Sheet1` `A1` remains selected

**Use-Case 2:**

- Activate `Sheet1`, select range `A1`
- Activate `Sheet2`
- Run `restoreTable`
- observe: range `Sheet1` `A1` is **not** selected, instead the range `Table1[#Data]` is selected

**Solution**

It's absolutely terrible, but this is the best solution I could find

```
Public Sub resotreTable_preserveSelection()
    Dim curSheet As Worksheet: Set curSheet = ActiveSheet
    Dim tableSheet As Worksheet: Set tableSheet = Range("Table1").Parent

    ' Change Sheet
    tableSheet.Activate

    ' Remember Selection / Active Ranges
    Dim originalSelection As Range:  Set originalSelection = Selection
    Dim originalActiveCell As Range: Set originalActiveCell = ActiveCell

    ' Restore Table
    Call restoreTable

    ' Restore Old Selection
    originalSelection.Select
    originalActiveCell.Activate

    ' Change Back to old sheet
    curSheet.Activate
End Sub
```

Note: in this case, the `original`* ranges are not necessary, but you get the point: you can buffer the original selection and restore it when you're finished

I really don't like excel

Answer (score -1):

Of course you don't have to select or activate the sheet to select/activate the cell. My way is to use "On Error Resume Next" and "On Error GoTo 0". Code below selects first cell in every worksheet of a workbook without selecting it. The worksheets are even very hidden on this stage.

```
On Error Resume Next
For i_wks = 1 To wb_macro.Worksheets.Count
    wb_macro.Worksheets(i_wks).Cells(1).Select
Next i_wks
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: This does not select the first cell on each worksheet, it just hides the error and keeps going to the next sheet.  The only reason this might appear to work is because cell A1 is the default selected cell on a new worksheet.